# NetBeans bug showing on example code in book "Pro JavaFX 8: A Definitive Guide" initializing objects in FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

In Chapter 3 of "Pro JavaFX 8: A Definitive Guide to Building Desktop, Mobile, and Embedded Java Clients", an example illustrating how to specify objects directly in an FXML file generates errors in NetBeans 8.0.2 (I downloaded the code from the book's site and all other examples I tried so far worked).

This FXML snippet:

```xml
<discount>
        <Utilities fx:constant="TEN_PCT"/>
</discount>
```

is supposed to initialize a field `discount` with the constant `TEN_PCT` defined in Utilities.java:

```java
package projavafx.fxmlbasicfeatures;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Utilities {
    public static final Double TEN_PCT = 0.1d;
    public static final Double TWENTY_PCT = 0.2d;
    public static final Double THIRTY_PCT = 0.3d;

    public static List<Integer> createList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

The tool tip error is "Constant 'TEN_PCT' is not defined for Utilities."

Another error in the same example appears at this point:

```java
<profits>
    <HashMap q1="1000" q2="1100" q3="1200" a4="1300"/>
</profits>
```

with the error "Class 'java.util.HashMap' does not support property 'q1' ", with analogous errors for the other keys.

What is the reason for these errors, and how can they be fixed?

Here's all the files (besides Utilities.java above):

FXMLBasicFeatures.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<?import projavafx.fxmlbasicfeatures.FXMLBasicFeaturesBean?>
<?import projavafx.fxmlbasicfeatures.Utilities?>
<?import java.lang.Double?>
<?import java.lang.Integer?>
<?import java.lang.Long?>
<?import java.util.HashMap?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<FXMLBasicFeaturesBean name="John Smith"
                       flag="true"
                       count="12345"
                       xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <address>12345 Main St.</address>
    <foreground>#ff8800</foreground>
    <background>
        <Color red="0.0" green="1.0" blue="0.5"/>
    </background>
    <price>
        <Double fx:value="3.1415926"/>
    </price>
    <discount>
        <Utilities fx:constant="TEN_PCT"/>
    </discount>
    <sizes>
        <Utilities fx:factory="createList">
            <Integer fx:value="1"/>
            <Integer fx:value="2"/>
            <Integer fx:value="3"/>
        </Utilities>
    </sizes>
    <profits>
        <HashMap q1="1000" q2="1100" q3="1200" a4="1300"/>
    </profits>
    <fx:define>
        <Long fx:id="inv" fx:value="9765625"/>
    </fx:define>
    <inventory>
        <fx:reference source="inv"/>
    </inventory>
    <products>
        <String fx:value="widget"/>
        <String fx:value="gadget"/>
        <String fx:value="models"/>
    </products>
    <abbreviations CA="California" NY="New York" FL="Florida" MO="Missouri"/>

</FXMLBasicFeaturesBean>
```

FXMLBasicFeaturesBean.java:

```
package projavafx.fxmlbasicfeatures;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FXMLBasicFeaturesBean {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private boolean flag;
    private int count;
    private Color foreground;
    private Color background;
    private Double price;
    private Double discount;
    private List<Integer> sizes;
    private Map<String, Double> profits;
    private Long inventory;
    private List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, String> abbreviations = new HashMap<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public boolean isFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Color getForeground() {
        return foreground;
    }

    public void setForeground(Color foreground) {
        this.foreground = foreground;
    }

    public Color getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public void setBackground(Color background) {
        this.background = background;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Double getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(Double discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public List<Integer> getSizes() {
        return sizes;
    }

    public void setSizes(List<Integer> sizes) {
        this.sizes = sizes;
    }

    public Map<String, Double> getProfits() {
        return profits;
    }

    public void setProfits(Map<String, Double> profits) {
        this.profits = profits;
    }

    public Long getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(Long inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public List<String> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAbbreviations() {
        return abbreviations;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FXMLBasicFeaturesBean{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ",\n\taddress='" + address + '\'' +
            ",\n\tflag=" + flag +
            ",\n\tcount=" + count +
            ",\n\tforeground=" + foreground +
            ",\n\tbackground=" + background +
            ",\n\tprice=" + price +
            ",\n\tdiscount=" + discount +
            ",\n\tsizes=" + sizes +
            ",\n\tprofits=" + profits +
            ",\n\tinventory=" + inventory +
            ",\n\tproducts=" + products +
            ",\n\tabbreviations=" + abbreviations +
            '}';
    }
}
```

FXMLBasicFeaturesMain.java:

```
package projavafx.fxmlbasicfeatures;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FXMLBasicFeaturesMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FXMLBasicFeaturesBean bean = FXMLLoader.load(
            FXMLBasicFeaturesMain.class.getResource(
                "/projavafx/fxmlbasicfeatures/FXMLBasicFeatures.fxml")
        );
        System.out.println("bean = " + bean);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the correct `import` statements in the FXML?

Comment: Yes, just included the whole file in question.

Comment: Looks totally valid to me. Can you include the other two classes?

Comment: Sure, there they are, thanks.

Comment: I do not have NetBeans, so I cannot re-create the problem. But on my IntelliJ idea, I do not get the error `Constant 'TEN_PCT' is not defined for Utilities`. Though I get a warning saying `Attribute q1 is not allowed here` while using `HashMap`, which IMO can be ignored as there is no error with the declaration itself.

Comment: Does it run? I suspect NetBeans just doesn't recognise this usage...

Comment: It does run, although the file will not open on Scene.

Comment: That's most probably because the fxml file doesn't have a standard javafx node as the root element. And SceneBuilder is meant for, well, building javafx scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the errors you see in the NetBeans editor are due to bugs in NetBeans itself. This is only an issue within the NetBeans editor, the `FXMLLoader` will happily process these statements as you noticed yourself, when running the sample application.

The first error happens because NetBeans doesn't seem to allow constant fields of which the type differs from the enclosing class' type. So the following snippet will work, because the constant Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY is a double itself:

```
<discount>
    <Double fx:constant="POSITIVE_INFINITY"/>
</discount>
```

The second error happens because the special use case of maps are simply not supported in the NetBeans editor.

I've already submitted bug reports for these two cases in NetBeans bugzilla.

`Constant 'TEN_PCT` is not defined for Utilities`:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=252416

`Class 'java.util.HashMap' does not support property 'q1'`:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=252417